# Chrome tabs too small to view their respective icons

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I have more than 50 tabs opened on Chrome and their width is soo small I cannot even view their respective icons.

EDIT : I tried :

- checked the `chrome://flags` for HiDPI but there is none.
- disabled all the add-ons manually and restarted
- tried the `--incognito` mode with only the `Tab Count` add-on enabled, then opened 8 urls as tabs, then opened 40 new empty tabs (40 times CTRL+t) and finally opened one last empty tab

Still have the same behavior : [image: screenshot of chromium with 49 tabs]

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: If you can't find any other solution, consider distributing your tabs over separate browser windows.

Comment: See my EDIT paragraph